# Google Map Functions but does not show map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The google map was working fine until a few weeks ago. The markers etc show but the map image does not, I just have a white screen. Another odd thing is that the buttons for zoom etc show but seem to be missing their styling. I can scroll around the page as before, and can zoom etc. I just dont see the map image.

I dont get any errors showing in my console.

Thanks for any help with this.

Here is the code that I am using

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>
        function initialize() {
            var myLatLng = { lat: 53.466055, lng: -2.632223 };
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.466051, -2.632229),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                scrollwheel: false
            }

           var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

            var markerHeadOffice = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 0),
                icon: '/Content/images/nic.png',
                title: 'Nichols plc, Newton-le-Willows, Merseyside'
            });
            var markerSouthWales = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: 51.6577671, lng: -3.8336524 },
                map: map,
                icon: '/Content/images/smallerNic.png',
                title: 'Nichols South Wales'
            });
            var markerSouth = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: 50.8541572, lng: -1.7532777 },
                map: map,
                icon: '/Content/images/smallerNic.png',
                title: 'Dayla Packaging'
            });
            var markerScotland = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: 56.1082775, lng: -3.9169815 },
                map: map,
                icon: '/Content/images/smallerNic.png',
                title: 'Nichols Dispense'
            });
            var markerManu = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: 51.9279492, lng: -2.5780233 },
                map: map,
                icon: '/Content/images/smallerNic.png',
                title: 'Manufacturing'
            });


            var contentString =
                '<div class="row" style="width:350px;height:150px;">'
                    //+ '<div class="col-sm-12">'
                   + '<div class="col-xs-4"><img src="/Content/images/mixed.png"/></div>'
                   + '<div class="col-xs-6">'
                   + 'Nichols plc<br/>'
                   + 'Laurel House<br/>'
                   + 'Woodland Park<br/>'
                   + 'Newton-le-Willows<br/>'
                   //+ '</div>'

                    + '</div></div>';
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });

            markerHeadOffice.addListener('click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, markerHeadOffice);
            });

            markerHeadOffice.setMap(map);
            markerSouthWales.setMap(map);
            markerSouth.setMap(map);
            markerScotland.setMap(map);
            markerManu.setMap(map);
      }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: All your calls to `[marker].setMap(map)` are redundant; you're already specifying the map property when you create each marker, which is all you need to do : `map: map`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add height to the #map element: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVZPBp

```
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your your quick response. I still have the same issue. The map already had a height set (the markers etc and controls show as they should, just not the map image).

Comment: I did copy and paste the code from your pen into my code and set the height/width as suggested. Its so frsutrating because it works in the pen just not in my code. The markers did not show ion your pen, could this be the source of the error?

Comment: The  bottom right controls (the + and -) and the yellow man also do not render properly, the boxes are there, and they work on click tho.

Comment: Also, if i drag what should be the little yellow man, the street view shows up

Comment: Would the JQuery version cause an issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

On the off-chance i removed this from my css

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

And voila, my map image came back. Hope this helps somebody else. Thanks to everyone who helped with this.